# Is mongodb's $facet faster than 2 separate queries?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to grab only 10 users at a time, but I also want to know how many there are total. Previously I did this using async and two separate aggregations, but I'm wondering if combining them into one would make it faster / less hard on the server.

```
Users.aggregate([{'$facet': {
    users: [{$limit: 10}],
    count: [{ "$group": {"sum": { "$sum": 1 }
      }}],
}}]).exec(function(err, results) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

});
```

Is this any faster that 2 separate queries? Or is facet just turning it into two separate queries? The queries may have some other stages added to them such as $match, if they're being searched.

Essentially I need them to be counted in full, but also only return the first 10.

Comment: `$facet` will only be useful when there is at least one `$match` stage at the top of the aggregation. Else it is better to use two separate queries.

Comment: Okay, so I was going to add the match to each query, but I can add it before the facet if that will work and be more efficient than 2 separate queries. Really the counting and limiting step are the only thing that needs to be different about them.